# Kubernetes: How do I connect Zeppelin+Spark deployment to mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, kubernetes, apache-zeppelin, kubernetes-helm

I have installed Spark + Zeppelin in my k8s cluster using the (slightly old) helm chart at

https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/spark

I would like my Zeppelin notebook to be able to connect to a mongodb running in the same cluster.

How do I accomplish this?

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark seems helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have deployments & services for mongoDB container ?
Have you used any namespace ?
For example: 1. kubectl get deployments -n <your namespace> 
2. kubectl get services -n <your namespace>
returns something relevant to the mongoDB?

Comment: @Investigator Yes, mongodb is running in a pod in the same namespace... as is the corresponding service.